# Vue 3: v-model helper is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I wrote myself a little helper for the vue 3 v-model binding. Strangely it does not work fully reactive. Internal changes get emitted in a correct way, external changes are not recognised. But if I use the same computed function within my component, everything works as expected.
How do I write the helper, to be fully reactive?

The helper:

```js
import { computed, SetupContext, WritableComputedRef } from 'vue';

export const vModel = <T>(val: T, context: SetupContext, binding = 'modelValue'): WritableComputedRef<T> =>
    computed({
        get: () => val,
        set: (value) => {
            context.emit(`update:${binding}`, value);
        },
    });
```

The sfc:

```js
<template>
    <div class="ms-deleteInput">
        <input class="ms-deleteInput__input" :label="label" v-model="inputVal" />
        <button @click="$emit('delete')" />
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: "deleteInput",
    props: {
        modelValue: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        label: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    setup(props, context) {

        // This works
        const inputVal = computed({
            get: () => props.modelValue,
            set: (value) => {
                context.emit(`update:modelValue`, value);
            },
        });

        // This works, but external changes of modelValue prop will not be detected:
        const inputVal = vModel(props.modelValue, context);

        return {
            inputVal,
        };
    },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not pass props to the helper, it won't track the props change in computed property.

Pass props instead of props.modelValue to the helper:

```
const inputVal = vModel(props, context);
```

Update the helper:

```
export const vModel = (props, binding) =>
computed({
    get: () => props.modelValue,
    set: (value) => {
        context.emit(`update:${binding}`, value);
    },
});
```

Comment: I have prepared a simple demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-qjknpb?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

Comment: BTW, the demo doesn't include the emit part, since you mentioned it works on your side, and it is a little inconvenient to code on stackblitz, check the MyComputed, it can accept the changes from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!
It works now with this:

```js
import { computed, SetupContext, WritableComputedRef } from 'vue';

export const vModel = <T>(props: Record<string, T>, context: SetupContext, binding = 'modelValue'): WritableComputedRef<T> =>
    computed({
        get: () => props[binding],
        set: (value) => {
            context.emit(`update:${binding}`, value);
        },
    });
```

but the typing ist not correct.
I get the error:

```
Argument of type 'Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<{ modelValue?: unknown; label?: unknown; } & { modelValue: string; label: string; } & {}> & { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string>'.
  'string & `on${string}`' and 'string' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I tried severall typings for the `props` within the function, but they all don't seem to be correct.
I could't find a good way of typing within the vue documentation.