# Vue 3: v-model helper typings

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

After getting the v-model helper working with the help given in [Vue 3: v-model helper is not reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807257/vue-3-v-model-helper-is-not-reactive) it works now with this:

```js
import { computed, SetupContext, WritableComputedRef } from 'vue';

export const vModel = <T>(props: Record<string, T>, context: SetupContext, binding = 'modelValue'): WritableComputedRef<T> =>
    computed({
        get: () => props[binding],
        set: (value) => {
            context.emit(`update:${binding}`, value);
        },
    });
```

but the typing ist not correct.
I get the error:

```
Argument of type 'Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<{ modelValue?: unknown; label?: unknown; } & { modelValue: string; label: string; } & {}> & { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string>'.
  'string & `on${string}`' and 'string' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I tried severall typings for the `props` within the function, but they all don't seem to be correct.
I could't find a good way of typing within the vue documentation.

Comment: It looks like you are writing a shorthand for v-model binding. The vueuse project does this see [useVModel](https://vueuse.org/core/useVModel/).